# Use same value in 2 alias sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have query like this.

```
SELECT
  ( SELECT StatusName
   FROM dbo.LMS_MST_Status
   WHERE MainStatusId = a.ParentID ) +'-'+ StatusName AS Value,

  ( SELECT StatusName
   FROM dbo.LMS_MST_Status
   WHERE MainStatusId = a.ParentID ) +'-'+ StatusName AS [Text]
FROM dbo.LMS_MST_Status a
WHERE ParentID > 0
  AND MainStatusID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [Text]
```

I which I have 2 alias i.e Value and Text but values of both are same. These columns are handled in front end as it is so I can't change front end code. I can't change even alias name. So I have made this query like above. But I have a feeling that it will affect performance of my application since I am using sub-query for both aliases. Can it be optimize?

Comment: Check execution plan, I think that query optimizer is smart enough to spot that it is the same subquery and executes it once ;)

Comment: really? that's awesome man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `left join`:

```
select
    b.StatusName +'-'+ a.StatusName AS [Value],
    b.StatusName +'-'+ a.StatusName AS [Text],
FROM dbo.LMS_MST_Status a
left join dbo.LMS_MST_Status b on a.ParentID = b.MainStatusId
WHERE ParentID > 0
AND MainStatusID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [Text]
```

You can also try with `inner join`(suggested by @Damien_The_Unbeliever):

```
select
    b.StatusName +'-'+ a.StatusName AS [Value],
    b.StatusName +'-'+ a.StatusName AS [Text],
FROM dbo.LMS_MST_Status a
inner join dbo.LMS_MST_Status b on a.ParentID = b.MainStatusId
WHERE ParentID > 0
AND MainStatusID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [Text]
```

Which will not create any `null` values and only fetch data if `a.ParentID = b.MainStatusId` condition satisfied.

Comment: It may even be inner join - depending on the exact data model.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `APPLY(CROSS or OUTER)` for this:

```
SELECT  ca.StatusName AS Value ,
        ca.StatusName AS [Text]
FROM    dbo.LMS_MST_Status a
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT    StatusName + '-' + a.StatusName AS StatusName
                      FROM      dbo.LMS_MST_Status
                      WHERE     MainStatusId = a.ParentID
                    ) ca
WHERE   ParentID > 0
        AND MainStatusID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY [Text]
```